# How to return IEnumerable Linq value with conditional statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a conditional `"if... else if..."` statement within an `IEnumerable` Linq query.  I'm getting the following error:

> not all code path return a value

Below is my code.

```
public IEnumerable<SASF> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
        {

            var context = new Entities();
            string myDate = "2014-03-18";
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);



            if (commSubGp == "F00")
            {


                var getAgriculture = from a in context.SASF                
                                     where a.RDate == date &&
                                     a.COMM_SGP.CompareTo("F00") <= 0
                                     orderby a.Conmkt, a.MKTTITL descending
                                     select a;

                return getAgriculture.ToList();
            }
            else if (commSubGp == "n10")
            {

                var getPetroleum = from p in context.SASF
                                   where p.RDate == date &&
                                   p.COMM_SGP == "n10"
                                   orderby p.Conmkt, p.MKTTITL descending
                                   select p;

                return getPetroleum.ToList();
            }

            return ??????;     // what should be here?   
        }
```

Comment: Well, you need to answer it yourself. What do you want to return if you dont give parameter commSubGp?

Comment: Return null if you don't want anything

Comment: Instead of returning `null` return an empty collection. Or throw an argument exception.

Comment: Put an `else` after your `else if{ }` tag. This will make things more logical to read by saying: Do this after everything else. That might help you to know what you want to return - such as returning `null`, or throwing a new exception: `throw new Exception("Message");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It actually isn't that hard. Create your result above your if cases and return it.

your default result is an empty one

for both the other cases and or future cases create a case in which they get filled in according to the correct criteria

```
 public IEnumerable<SASF> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
    {

        var context = new Entities();

        //ALSO Change
        //string myDate = "2014-03-18";
        //DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);

        var date = new DateTime(2014,3,18);

        //Create a result in the type you want to return.
        var result = new List<SASF>();

        switch(commSubGp)
        {
            case "F00": //Agriculture

                result = (from a in context.SASF                
                             where a.RDate == date &&
                             a.COMM_SGP.CompareTo(commSubGp) <= 0
                             orderby a.Conmkt, a.MKTTITL descending
                             select a).ToList();

                break;
            case "n10": //petroleum
                result = (from p in context.SASF
                           where p.RDate == date &&
                           p.COMM_SGP == commSubGp
                           orderby p.Conmkt, p.MKTTITL descending
                           select p).ToList();
                break;
        }

        return result;     
    }
```

Comment: This `var result = new IEnumerable<SASF>();` should not compile, you can't create instances of an interface. `var result = Enumerable.Empty<SASF>();` would work.

Comment: Here you're creating a list that you're going to just throw away in every single valid case.  You're better off waiting until you actually hit that case to do so.  And `Enumerable.Empty` better conveys the intention of what's going on than newing a list that you just happen to know will never have items added to it.

Comment: not sure what u mean with that, but i'm sure this would work. I also didn't let the return occur in the cases so the OP would see only 1 list is used. There probably are better ways to write it, i'll give you that.

Comment: This code, as is, will not compile.  You are returning a variable that is not definitely assigned.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way would be to either return `null`, an empty enumerable `Enumerable.Empty<SASF>()` or throw an `ArgumentException`, depending on what you need.

If "F00" and "n10" are the only valid values that `commSubGp` can have, you should throw an ArgumentException, for this parameter. The compiler will stop asking for a return in that case.

Even cleaner: Make this parameter a enum or bool. For example an enum `ReportType` that only has the values `Agriculture` and `Petroleum`.

Comment: You should not be returning null.  Either return an empty sequence, throw an exception, or ensure that the situation cannot come up to begin with.

Comment: Well, IMO in some cases, null is a valid way to go. In his case I would tend to the ArgumentException as I mentioned or use an enum or bool to avoid the situation in the first place (as mentioned, too) ...

Answer (score 2):

You are querying the almost similar query and ordering by the same columns after filtering. You could make your code a bit more easier to maintain if you add the specific filters with the switch statement and throw not implemented exception if someone is giving a parameter which is not supported, also the case of null parameter must be somehow handled.

```
public IEnumerable<SASF> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
{
    var context = new Entities();
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-03-18");
    var sasf = (from s context.SASF
                where a.RDate == date
                select s);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(commSubGp))
    {
        switch (commSubGp)
        {
            case "F00":
                sasf = (from s in sasf
                        s.COMM_SGP.CompareTo("F00") <= 0
                        select s);
                break;

            case "n10":
                sasf = (from s in sasf
                        s.COMM_SGP == "n10"
                        select s);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(String.Format("commSubGp {0} not implemented", commSubGp));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter commSubGp is null");
    }

    return sasf.OrderBy(p => p.Conmkt).ThenByDescending(p => p.MKTTITL).ToList();      
}
```

Comment: make the n10 and F00 inside the linq typeSafe, then it's just ultimately right; => saw we almost had the same solution :s; +1 for argumentException and more maintainable code

Comment: I wouldn't go with a `NotImplementedException` here.  It'd probably be better to go with an `ArgumentException`.  `NotImplementedException` is generally reserved for when an entire method doesn't exist because it either hasn't been implemented yet, or it's not sensible for it to have an implementation ever.  Here there is simply an argument with an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this depends on what you actually want to return

```
return Enumerable.Empty<SASF>();
```

or

```
return null;
```

or throw an exception...

Answer (score 0):

```
return new List<SASF>();
```

Or an exception or null.

Answer (score -2):

Define a new variable as

```
IEnumerable<SASF> sasf = null;
```

And return it `return sasf;`

```
public IEnumerable<SASF> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
{
  IEnumerable<SASF> sasf;
  if(condition)
  {
    //your stuff and put it in sasf
  }
  else if(condition)
  {
    //your stuff and put it in sasf
  }
  return sasf;
}
```

Comment: You might as well just use `return null;`.

Comment: Shouldn't he set sasf = his stuff instead of returning it in the conditions?

Comment: @Hinek well yes he can set sasf = his stuff. I didn't mark it in answer just put a way to handle the return type of a function :)

Comment: @Dirk, yes we can return null here but then OP needs to handle this properly.

Comment: I guess we just have a different understanding of `//return your stuff` ;)

Comment: @Hinek, yes I avoid to add OP's code (the logic within the if else consition) there; just put my view. Answer updated now.

Comment: This won't compile as you're using `sasf` before it is definitely assigned.

Comment: It will now compile, but you shouldn't be returning a `null` sequence.  You should really be either returning an empty sequence or throwing an exception.